# Fibonacci sequence C problems

Tags: c

I was solving the problem... But I don't know why it does when a number greater than 200 is entered, it becomes an infinite loop.  I used the recursive function. And I also only can use this function. What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int n){   
    if (n<=0) return 0;
    else if(n==1 || n==2) return 1; 
    else {
        return f(n-1)+f(n-2);
    }
}

int main()    
{   
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("%d", f(n));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the number is to big for `int`

Comment: The largest fibonacci number that fits in `int` is `n=46`

Comment: Actually, it's not an infinite loop, it's just a very, very long loop.  Computing Fibonacci numbers is a classic example (probably *the* classic example) of when recursion should *not* be used (at least, not without [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).

Comment: For n=46, my computer (a decently fast, modern laptop) took over 10 seconds to (correctly) compute the value 1836311903.  For n=200, I estimate it would have taken 9,203,321,947,172,577,060,265,858 years.

Comment: @SteveSummit Only the lifetime of a few billion universes. Are you in a rush?

Comment: *"I also only can use this function"* Not sure exactly what that means. Does it just mean that you have to use the function signature `int f(int n)`?  Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> … it becomes an infinite loop.

If you are judging whether the program is in an infinite loop by waiting for it to finish, you cannot distinguish between it being in a very long loop and it being in an infinite loop unless you wait forever, which I doubt you have done.

When you ask for `f(200)`, the call to `f` evaluates `f(199)` and `f(198)`. Then the first of those calls to `f` evaluates `f(198)` and `f(197)`, and the second evaluates `f(197)` and `f(196)`. When you follow this tree of calls, there are very roughly 10<sup>41</sup> calls involved. So your program never terminates while you are waiting because evaluating that many calls would take eons.

(The number of calls for a given input *n* is going to be very similar to the Fibonacci sequence for *n*, and the ratios between numbers approaches (1+sqrt(5))/2, so the number of calls will be around (1+sqrt(5)/2)<sup>*n*</sup> times some constant depending on the initial terms.)